# vimscript regex: write multiple matches in array

Tags: regex, vim

I wrote a regex for vim which should find filenames. it looks like that:

```
let fileMatch = '\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]\+\.\)\+[a-zA-Z0-9]\+'
let fileName = matchstr(
    \ a:input_line,
    \ fileMatch
    \ )
```

Let's assume, that `a:input_line` has the value of:

```
(test/the/plugins.vim:13:2) (test/the/pluginsies.vim:13:2)
```

My goal is to have `plugins.vim` and `pluginsies.vim` in an array.
I will work through that array afterwords.

Now if I echo fileName, I only get the first match: `plugins.vim`.

So, how can I save multiple matches in an array?

## final solution

```
let fileMatch = '\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]\+\.\)\+[a-zA-Z0-9]\+'
let fileName = matchstr(
    \ a:input_line,
    \ fileMatch
    \ )
let result_list = map(split(a:input_line, fileMatch . '\zs'),'matchstr(v:val, fileMatch)')
```

Comment: i editited the example string, to show that it can be more complicated

Comment: Vim already offers a notion of a file identifier `:help isfname` so your regexp can be simplified to: `'\f\+`.

Answer (score 2):

`matchstr()` will only return the first match. You can use loop to get all matched strings.

I noticed that you will ignore the filenames with spaces. so this one-liner may help to get all matched strings in a list:

```
let result_list = map(split(a:input_line),'matchstr(v:val, fileMatch)')
```

It will return:

```
['plugins.vim', 'pluginsies.vim']
```

Comment: thx, so i have to split the string in before via space as delimiter? it is somehow possible that i can split bey my fileMatch regex?

Comment: i read that split() will remove the matched part, so i can't use the filePathRegex i created as split pattern. I had to add ```\zs``` to the end of the regex

Comment: as I said, you dont have to split. for your example, split() makes it easier. You can use match()/matchstr() in a loop to get all matched string. for your 2nd comment.you can split with your filename pattern and including the matched string in split(). and last,  I don't like that you read an answer and edit the Question to break the answer.. :(